# How the lw (load word) instruction works on the MIPS Unicycle (Implementation)

Tags: computer-architecture, mips

I'm reading the *Computer Organization and Design* book from *David A. Patterson* and *John L. Hennessy*. Specifically, I have a question about the implementation of a MIPS Unicycle.

So, in the book, they show how to implement the MIPS Unicycle using this architeture:

[image]

My question is: How is possible to the **load word instruction (lw)** to work using this architeture? This is not well explained in the book, so let me explain to you what it's not very clear to me.

The **load word** instruction has this format:

```
6 bits for OPCODE
5 bits for the Rd
5 bits for the Rt
16 bits for the offset

Rt <- Mem(Rd + offset)
```

So, in a simple way, it is possible to say that the load word instruction works this way using that architeture: The instruction is decoded and the *Rd* goes to the **Read Register 1** port of the *Registers Bank*, while *Rt* goes to *Write Register* port. Then, the **ALU** sums the *Rd* with the *offset* and send the result to the *address* port in the memory. The MemRead signal is activated, so the corresponding word is passed to the output. This word goes directly to the *Write Data* port in the *Registers Bank*. Now, the *RegWrite* signal is activated, so the word is stored in *Rt*.

This seems ok, but my question is: **How this is done using only one clock cycle?**

Specifically, I'm talking about the memory reading and the register writing. In my understanding, both of this operations are clock-sensitive. You can only read the memory or write in the Register Bank if there's a rising edge.

That said, how is it possible to the memory reading to be made in the middle of two clocks edges? This **must** be done this way, otherwise on the next rising edge the Mem(Rd + offset) value will not be in the Write Data port of the *Bank Register* and trash will be written.

I hope you guys could understand me. Thank you very much

Comment: asynchronous static RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [text](http://repositorio-aberto.up.pt/bitstream/10216/59975/1/000135086.pdf) in the section `3.4.1` states:

> All the blocks are asynchronous except the PCounter.

I.e. The registers and the memory are not clocked.

I believe this text is based on the book you are referring to (or they have the same sources), and they have almost the same diagram.